# How to get the stage width of a loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, stage

I'm loading an SWF that displays a slideshow of images into another stage. When I use `stage.stageHeight` or `stage.stageWidth` inside the loaded SWF I get the width and height of the stage that loaded the SWF instead of the loaded SWF stage.

My question is, how do I get the width and hight of a loaded SWF from within the loaded SWF itself and not the main stage?

Comment: I'm no pro on loading SWFs into others, but maybe you can try `this.stage.stageHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to read the swf metadata. You can use [`com.senocular.utils.SWFReader`](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/utils/SWFReader.as) for this:

```
package
{
import com.senocular.utils.SWFReader;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

[SWF(width="800", height="200", backgroundColor="0x8B8B8B")]
public class astest extends Sprite
{
    public function astest()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKb);
    }

    protected function onKb(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        var swf:SWFReader = new SWFReader(root.loaderInfo.bytes);

        trace("swf.width: "+swf.width);
        trace("swf.height: "+swf.height);
    }

}
}
```

output:

```
swf.width: 800
swf.height: 200
```

Be sure to pass the `loaderInfo` of the loaded swf file rather than the loader.

Answer (score 0):

The loaded swf's [`LoaderInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#loaderInfo) [`height`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#height) and [`width`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#width) will give the original stage size. That data isn't available until the swf is done loading though, so you should wait for the `LoaderInfo` instance to dispatch `Event.COMPLETE` before accessing them or it will throw an error.